# try-catch NullPointerException Error within two different classess

Tags: java, file

I have a `NullPointerException` Within the `Tournament` Class and the `Test` Class. I call the method of the `Tournament` to define in the `Test` class, then i assign it in the Tournament class to create `Team` objects. it gives me a `NullPointerException` on `Tournament tour = new Tournament();` and `File file = new(fileLocation);`.

i think its because i declared the wrong file path, but the file is in the project folder.To make it easier i set the directory of the file in the `Test` class to exactly know where the problem is and also change file if i needed. Please comment if you need any more blocks of the classes.

Test Class:

```
 Tournament tour = new Tournament();
 tour.setFile("Tourney2Teams.csv");
```

Tournament :

```
Scanner input;
    public String fileLocation;

    public void setFile(String x)
    {
        this.fileLocation=x;
    }
    File file = new File(fileLocation);
```

and this is the method to read the file:

```
public void readingFile()
    {
        try{
            input = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.print("File Not Found\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hard to see what's going on with that little amount of code, and no stack trace. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: Do you have debugger?

Comment: Please add full code, can't understand what you are doing. Like in your tournament class you are initializing file outside any method or constructor, why? And in your Test class you are creating Tournament object and and executing set method outside of any method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialise the file variable inside of the `setFile` method.

```
public void setFile(String x)
{
    this.fileLocation = x;
    file = new File(fileLocation);
}
File file;
```

Currently, it's trying to initialise the file using `fileLocation` before you've set the location, hence the NullPointerException.

To further explain, when you construct the Tournament, it initialises all variables, which means it calls `new File(fileLocation)` as you've asked it to. It doesn't matter that you've placed the method first in your code; fact is when it creates a new instance, `fileLocation = null` and you won't get a chance to set it before it tries to initialise it.

Comment: Edit: Added to answer

Comment: Thanks, keep up the good answers around here. I've edited it a bit so that it reads clearer but so far so good.

Comment: Cheers :). Decided it's about time I give back for all the help I've gotten from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are initialising the `file` in the `Tournament` class at class construction time, but `fileLocation` is initialised after that in the `setFile` method.  To solve this move the construction of `File` into the `setFile` method:

```
class Tournament {

    private File file;
    public void setFile(String fileLocation)
    {
        this.file = new File(fileLocation);
    }
    // ...
}
```

or create the file in a constructor instead:

```
class Tournament {

    private File file;
    public Tournament(String fileLocation)
    {
        this.file = new File(fileLocation);
    }
    // ...
}
```

In both these examples the `fileLocation` member variable didn't seem to be needed so it has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong path will never throw a `NullPointerException`, so problem is not in here.

EDIT:
`File` can throw a `NullPointerException` when the specified path is `null`. And you're calling it before you initialize the `fileLocation`, try

```
public Tournament(String x){
     fileLocation=x;
     file = new File(fileLocation);
}
```